# standalone pushfilter: jetty.server.request not found

Tags: jetty, servlet-filters, jetty-9, server-push

I'm working on a standalone-filter to extend our webapp (BaseX) if it's used with jetty. 
The goal is, to push some additionial resources when the response is beeing sent. 
The webapp defines, which resources have to be pushed.

With embedded jetty, all goes well. But when deploying BaxeX als servlet to jetty and starting with jettx:run-forked,  i get this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Request
at org.basex.http2.BaseXJettyPushFilter.doFilter(BaseXJettyPushFilter.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
```

...

This is the filter's pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.basex</groupId>
  <artifactId>basex-jetty-push-filter</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>basex-jetty-push-filter</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jetty.version>9.4.6.v20170531</jetty.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-alpn-server</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.http2</groupId>
      <artifactId>http2-common</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.http2</groupId>
      <artifactId>http2-server</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/ -->
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  </project>
  ...
```

and i'm loading it as dependency here:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.basex</groupId>
    <artifactId>basex-parent</artifactId>
    <version>9.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <name>BaseX API</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.basex</groupId>
      <artifactId>basex</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.basex</groupId>
      <artifactId>basex-jetty-push-filter</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.xqj</groupId>
      <artifactId>basex-xqj</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.xmldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmldb-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

It's clear why i can't access server-classes from within the webapp! The webapp shouldn't have any dependencies to the surrounding servlet-container, because it may change..

That's why i implemented the filter standalone, but somehow it still can't access the server.Request-class. 
Jetty's PushCacheFilter also uses the jetty.request-class, it should be possible!

Here's the filter:
https://github.com/BodoWissemann/basex-jetty-push-filter

How can i solve this problem? I'm stuck :(

Thx a lot!

Bodo

Answer (score 0):

**Simone Bordet answered my question:**

"@BodoWissemann you have it right that Servlet Container classes must be hidden to deployed web applications, and that is why you get the NoClassDefFoundError when you deploy your web application to Jetty and not when you run it embedded.

Jetty's PushCacheFilter works because we have a default system classes rule for it in the web application classloader, see https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-webapp/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.java#L128.

You should do the same for your BaseXJettyPushFilter: put it in the server classpath and define a system classes rule for it in the web application classloader.
I recommend you read the documentation about creating a custom Jetty module and how to define a server classes rule following this documentation and this example.

Note that in Servlet 4 you won't need any of this because the API to use, PushBuilder, has been standardized in the Servlet APIs."